# Google Inbox keyboard shortcut for adding bcc

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Does Google Inbox have keyboard interactions/shortcuts for adding someone as bcc when replying to an email?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. List view: arrow keys to highlight message
2. "Open": <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. "Reply in a new window": <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
4. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> * 3: highlight the drop down arrow for the "to" field
5. <kbd>space</kbd>: expand drop down
6. <kbd>tab</kbd> to bcc field
7. Add email

Answer (score 0):

other shortcuts available:

[image]

*invoked by **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>?</kbd>**